# open file dir problem

Tags: c, linux

I'm running an Linux OS and trying to open file in C compiler like this :

```
  file = fopen ("list.txt", "r");
```

but the file is not opend!

and when i put the full path like this :

```
   file = fopen ("/home/rami/Desktop/netfilter/list.txt", "r");
```

it is working!

why the first example is not working?

- the list.txt is in the same directory of the c file
  thanks.

Comment: When you run the program, are you running it from the same folder as the c-file and list.txt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the directory of the `C` file that matters, it's *[your current working directory](http://www.aip.de/~weber/doc/gs/node104.html)* that does. Try

```
cd /home/rami/Desktop/netfilter
```

before running the executable.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know **WHY** the file didn't open?

Always check the return value of `fopen()` (and most other functions) and report back a readable error.

```
file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if (!file) {
    perror("file open");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

*I see you've already found out what your problem is, but the above is a suggestion for the future (and to change your current project)*

Answer (score 0):

Is the executable also in the same dir as that of list.txt?

Edit: Actually that doesnt matter. It's the current working dir as per the other answer.